# In C# .NET, is there a reason for no copy constructor for StringDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary, stringdictionary

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but hear me out:

```
Dictionary<string, string> genericDict = new Dictionary<string, string>;
genericDict.Add("blah", "bloop");
// Use the copy constructor to create a copy of this dictionary
return new Dictionary<string, string>(genericDict);
```

In the above code sample, I can create a copy of a generic dictionary.

Now suppose I'm using a System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary, because I don't feel like typing the "string" types everywhere. StringDictionary has no copy constructor! In fact, it only has the default constructor.

Sure, I can iterate through the StringDictionary and add each key/value pair manually, but I don't want to :-P

Why no copy constructor? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `StringDictionary` type is rather obsolete.  I think that `Dictionary<String,String>` is what you want to use here.

The `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` type implements some strongly-typed interfaces (`ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`) which makes it more useful than the `StringDictionary` type.

While the `StringDictionary` type *is* strongly typed I wouldn't advise its use for the sake of laziness alone.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that for the generic Dictionary<typeKey, typeValue>, not for the specialized StringDictionary?
I was just wondering why that very handy overload wasn't implemented for the specialized StringDictionary.

Comment: I think he's saying that the generic type DOES have this sort of constructor, but the old specialized dictionary does not.

Comment: @Pandincus: Keltex is correct - the specialized dictionary does not that overloaded constructor as it is an older type and most likely the copy constructor was not considered at that time.  Regardless, I am highly recommending that you use `Dictionary<String,String>` and abandon `StringDictionary`.

Comment: I guess laziness only gets you so far. OK, you've convinced me. :-D

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use a StringDictionary (perhaps to support a *legacy application*), you can create an extension method:

```
public static StringDictionary NewCopy(this StringDictionary olddict)
{
    var newdict = new StringDictionary();
    foreach (string key in olddict.Keys)
    {
        newdict.Add(key, olddict[key]);
    }
    return newdict;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
StringDictionary newdict = olddict.NewCopy();
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the consensus -- you're better off using `Dictionary<string, string>`. But if you don't like typing the generic types all the time, you could create your own subclass:

```
public class StringDict : Dictionary<string, string>
{
  // duplicate all Dictionary's constructors here, calling the base constructor for each. 
}
```

*Et Voila!* Whenever you want to use a string `Dictionary`, you use `StringDict` instead.

Comment: I think that StrigDict offers a more compelling feature set.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to type the "string" types anywhere but are otherwise happy with `Dictionary<string,string>`, then create a new class that subclasses `Dictionary<string,string>` and just don't override any methods.  You can even call it `StringDictionary`, as long as it's in a different namespace.